# Why is the size of duplicated table so much smaller than original?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, storage, select-into

I have a table [ExampleSource] where SQL Server Management Studio indicates the following storage statistics:

- Index space: 58 MB
- Row count: 28269319
- Data space: 4,567 MB

I copied the table using the following command with the intention of benchmarking various index configurations:

```
SELECT * 
INTO [ExampleSource_Test] 
FROM [ExampleSource]
```

I noticed something surprising as soon as the query finished. The size of the data in the new test table was dramatically smaller:

- Index space: 0.016 MB
- Row count: 28269319
- Data space: 2,820 MB

The new table has the same data, just no index / primary key. I added a primary key (identical to the original) to the new Test table with the following results:

- Index space: 22.227 MB
- Row count: 28269319
- Data space: 2,820 MB

Not surprising that adding the key didn't increase the Data Space.

Here is the table structure if that helps:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExampleSource]
(
    [C1] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [C2] [nvarchar](9) NOT NULL,
    [C3] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [C4] [int] NOT NULL,
    [C5] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [C6] [int] NOT NULL,
    [C7] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [C8] [date] NULL,
    [C9] [decimal](29, 9) NULL,
    [C10] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [C11] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [C12] [decimal](29, 9) NULL,
    [C13] [nvarchar](3) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ExampleSource] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([C2] ASC, [C3] ASC, [C4] ASC, [C5] ASC, [C6] ASC, [C1] DESC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
             ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

The original table is a result of many row inserts over time - generally a few thousand at a time. No updates or deletes. I'm wondering what accounts for this drastic space difference from the original table (for both index and data)? I'm guessing that SQL Server is doing a lot of optimization/reorganization of data when copying all at once, but I'm looking for a good explanation of why there could have been so much wasted space in the original table. Is there some maintenance that I could/should be occasionally running on the table to prevent this bloat?

Comment: Side note: `nvarchar(1)` is useless - use `nchar(1)` instead. Since you can only ever store a maximum of 1 character, making this a variable length column is only adding a 2-byte per row overhead (that you do not incur if you use `nchar(1)` instead). Same goes for `nvarchar(3)`

Comment: marc_s, I see your point about nvarchar(1). The same logic applies to nvarchar(3) from a storage perspective only, though. If I have variable length items, I don't want to use nchar. Trimming white space is annoying.

Comment: Agreed - but if you store strings that are 90%+ always just 1 or 3 characters long, it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that original table had one or more variable-length columns which was dropped. In this case, try to use [DBCC CLEANTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174418.aspx)

Second possible reason is fragmentation, try to check it with the query:

```
select a.index_id, name, avg_fragmentation_in_percent  
    from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(N'YourDatabase'), OBJECT_ID(N'ExampleSource'), NULL, NULL, NULL) a
    join sys.indexes AS b ON a.object_id = b.object_id AND a.index_id = b.index_id
```

If for some indexes fragmented, reorganize them:

```
ALTER INDEX Index_name on Table_Name REORGANIZE WITH (LOB_COMPACTION=ON)
```

If this does not help much, try to use "ALTER INDEX REBUILD" (and dropping and re-creating index as last choice).

Comment: The table structure has not been changed since it was initially created. I'm tempted to try DBCC CLEANTALBE, but the article linked in your answer suggests that it 'should not be executed as a routine maintenance task'.

Comment: Maybe index fragmented (I just edited the answer). This (rarely) can be even when you just add new rows.

Comment: After I looked at the clustered index in the edited question, I think that the problem could very well be due to the splitting pages during insertion.

Comment: Is there a way to test that hypothesis? I have not modified the original table in any way yet.

Comment: First, try to run query from my answer (dm_db_index_physical_stats) do you see any fragmentation?

Comment: The query returns 97.9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122457/discussion-between-c31983-and-olegaxenow).